# What would be the appropriate HTTP method to rename a resource in RESTful APIs

Tags: rest, http, post, rename, put

Will we use `PUT` or `POST` when the identity of resource itself is changing from *oldname* to *newname* in the web service?

Comment: https://www.greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc4918.html#METHOD_MOVE

Answer (score 2):

Typically `POST` is used to create a resource. Since you're not creating a resource better option seems to be `PUT` but... `PUT` request are idempotent - it means more or less - *repeatable* in terms of outcome, further reading might be found [here](http://restcookbook.com/HTTP%20Methods/idempotency/). Also `PUT` needs to contain the whole resource. Thus, maybe `PATCH` is the right choice?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **PATCH** request to update data in webservice.

**POST** means create new and **PUT** means insert, replace if already exists.

Find more details - [click here](https://www.soapui.org/learn/api/rest-request-method-verbs/)